# Upload Document to a sharepoint 2010 library using jquery from external MVC application

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, web-services, sharepoint

What are the ways to upload document to a SharePoint 2010 library using asp.net MVC 4 application (coded in jquery).

The SharePoint site is a hosted as a separate site and my web application is hosted on a different site.

I could use SharePoint web services but I want to code the entire upload using jquery.

I need to call the web service in my external asp.net application
Upload the document with the meta data into the SharePoint site.
Checkout/check-in an existing document using the windows credential

Is there any other way /resource of doing this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

[SPServices](http://spservices.codeplex.com/) from codeplex will let you call the SharePoint webservices relatively easily from jQuery. The [CopyIntoItems](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/copy.copy.copyintoitems.aspx) call can be used to put a base64 encoded document into SharePoint and then edit the metadata after that.